# Как объединить 2 функции на фото 1, для избежание повторяющегося кода. Фото 2 - функция с сервиса

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

```
public pageEvent(event: PageEvent): void {
    this._authorsService.getAuthors(++event.pageIndex, this.elementsPerPage)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this._destroy$),
      )
      .subscribe((authors: IPaginatedAuthors) => {
        this.authors = authors.authors;
      });
  }

  private _getAuthors(): void {
    this._authorsService.getAuthors(this.pageNumber, this.elementsPerPage)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this._destroy$),
      )
      .subscribe((authors: IPaginatedAuthors) => {
        this.authors = authors.authors;
        this.length = authors.meta.records ?? 0;
      });
  }


public getAuthors(pageNumber: number, elementsPerPage: number): Observable<IPaginatedAuthors> {
    const parameters = {
      limit: elementsPerPage,
      page: pageNumber,
    };

    return this._http.get<IPaginatedAuthors>('/api/authors', { params: parameters });
  }
```

Comment: Трудно понять откуда и как вызываютс функции

Comment: почему в одном случае выставляется `length` а в другом нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант

```
  public pageEvent(event: PageEvent): void {
    this._getAuthors(++event.pageIndex, this.elementsPerPage)
  }

  private _getAuthors(pageNumber, elementsPerPage): void {
    this._authorsService.getAuthors(pageNumber, elementsPerPage)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this._destroy$),
      )
      .subscribe((authors: IPaginatedAuthors) => {
        this.authors = authors.authors;
        this.length = authors.meta.records ?? 0;
      });
  }
```

Разумеется если где-то ещё вызывается _getAuthors делать

```
_getAuthors(this.pageNumber, this.elementsPerPage)
```

PS: Синтаксис поправьте, если что :)